# How can user read / write own data with firestore on vue.js?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

My goal is to let user only read and write its own submitted data.

When submitting data, I can fetch it, but it's currently available for all users to see.

Using new security rule on firestore:

```
    service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /users/{userId} {
          allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
          allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
        }
      }
    }
```

I get `Uncaught Error in onSnapshot: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.` in the console on chrome even though my collection is named `users` and my document id is the user uid.

Here I'm using interpolation and v-for in order to get the data to display:  `<sidebar-link id="user.uid" :to="`/${user.title}`" :name="`${user.title}`" icon="tim-icons icon-atom" v-for="(user) in users" :key="user.title"/>`

[image]

Here I'm trying to fetch the data from firestore:

```
      created () {
          db.collection('users').onSnapshot(res => {
            const changes = res.docChanges()
            changes.forEach(change => {
              if (change.type === 'added') {
                this.users.push({
                  ...change.doc.data(),
                  id: change.doc.id
                })
              }
            })
          })
        }
```

adding the if statement on `read, update and delete` obviously allows me to see the data again, but it also allows all users to see it which is not the security I'm aiming at.

Comment: Could you edit the question to show the exact queries you would like to allow or reject depending on who runs them?  Security rules don't have meaning without also knowing the specific queries they are supposed to protect.

Comment: I will point out also that your current rules allow anyone to create a document in `users`, even using a document ID that is not their own ID.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I added the query. But it is also a part of my question, I am not sure about the best practice / query to use here. Reading through https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries I find some information about filtering, so I guess ultimately I need to filter the data e.g that user can see data in document because document string has matching string with its UID. However, when using this.user in where I am fetching the data as opposed to where I'm submitting it, where I'm fetching it, "this.user" seems to not work. So I am unsure how to fetch user uid

Comment: Something like `db.collection('users').doc(this.user).onSnapshot(res => { ` should work, or at least putting this.user works when submitting the data. But I'm getting errors that it needs to be a non empty string. So the confusion is, how do I then fetch "user uid" which is the same as the document string, and it needs to be users uid always.